# simplify $a=a*b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Normally in algebra, you can simplify an equation such as $a=a*b$ by dividing both sides by a common coefficient. For example, $\frac {a}{a}=\frac {ab}{a} \rightarrow1=b$. Obviously $b = 1$ is a correct solution to the equation, but clearly also is $a = 0$. Both solutions can be found inuitively, but it occurs to me that there should be a procedure that yields both, and I don't even know one that yields $0$ at all.

Comment: $a-ab=0 \Rightarrow a(1-b)=0$

Comment: When you divided by $a$ you implicitly assumed $a\ne 0$. It remains to consider the case $a=0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$ a = a \ast b \Rightarrow a \cdot (1-b) =0$$ which says either $b=1$ or $a=0$ because when the product of $2$ numbers is $0$, then either one of them has to be $0$.

Comment: This only happens in an Integral domain.

Comment: Note the algebra-precalculus tag - in this setting, we can assume integral domains.

Answer (score 3):

This question has a good application of the [zero product property.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-product_property)$$\begin{aligned}a &=ab & \\ a - a b &=  0\\a(1 - b) & = 0  \\ \therefore a = 0 \vee  b = 1\end{aligned} $$

Comment: $a=0$ OR $b=1$, not necessarily both at the same time.

Comment: Good point... editing now.